# How to make a token that is unique and hard to guess and predict?

Tags: mysql, node.js, algorithm, token, uuid

I need to generate a token once my users have authenticate with a 3rd party(Facebook, or Twitter). I will give this token back to the client and they will be able to access all the users information using it.

I need the token to be hard to guess and hard to predict. (Hard meaning it would take a day or two to guess with a modern desktop)

---

MySQL has the function `UUID()` that generates a value that is unique but the documentation also says its not unguessable or unpredictable. I'm not sure if that means it's not hard to guess or predict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [tons of node.js modules](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/uuid), that do exactly what you need. Popular picks:

- [node-uuid](https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/node-uuid)
- [shotid](https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/shortid)

Comment: I'd go for whirlpool(timestamp*username), or something like that.

Comment: I was looking at node-uuid. It doesn't say anything about guessability or predicability in the document but it seems to rely on a lot of random bits and I feel comfortable that is enough to make it hard to guess or predict.